# Where can I get a student ID in Poland (Wroclaw) using my American Student ID?

Tags: poland, paperwork, study

I am a student in America and I have just traveled to Poland. There are a lot of trams here and tickets are cheaper for student tickets then for normal tickets. I have my American student ID card but it is not a legal form of ID in Poland. I know there is a place I can get a Polish/International student ID which I can use, but I don't know where to get it and how much it costs.

I am going to Wroclaw today, and wondering how much it would potentially cost, and where exactly I can get one?

What do I need to provide to prove that I am a student - is my American student ID enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only international student ID I am aware of is ISIC and in Poland you can get one in one of the places listed on their Polish web site: http://www.isic.pl/index.php/gdzie-mozna-wyrobic-karte.html

I don't know if they will be willing to issue you with a card based on your American student ID though. It might depend on local branch managers interpretation.

You should also check if you are entitled for travel discount, the rules seem to be different for different cities and modes of transport. It seems that the ISIC card is enough for trams in Wroclaw: http://www.wroclaw.pl/uprawnienia_do_ulg.dhtml

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid there is not such a thing as national Polish student ID. There are only the IDs of respective Polish universities which you need to be enrolled to (or be a part of student exchange program) in order to get one.

However, from my observation - they will accept foreign student ID (and some international cards like ISIC or Euro26) in most places - especially cinemas, museums.

The problems may be with national railways - you may have problems getting discount ticket if you are not enrolled to *Polish* university.

Comment: very good answer but lacks locations

Comment: Railways are major PITA. I've had problem when bought tickets for my family. Cashier asked how old my son is (10 at the time) and gave me what I thought was the correct ticket. But then in the train the conductor said it's not valid, because he's not attending Polish school. I had to pay a fine. Apparently there are two kinds of discounts, one base on age (33% IIRC), other based on attending school (50%).